# PHP parsing non existing config files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I'm using Laravel Valet and Homebrew. I'm not sure however if this question is a general PHP or Laravel specific.

I have trouble setting up Xdebug and OCI8. In the process of elimination, I decided to remove it completely from my system.  To my surprise, I'm not able to remove xdebug. As you can see below when I run php --ini I do not see xdebug listed or pearsed:

[image]

When I run however:

```
phpinfo();
```

I get the following:

[image]

I have no idea why is it still showing. It looks like it is still being parsed and listed as a loaded extension. I assume this is a source of my problem since I'm trying to edit not the correct extension config files.

Thanks!

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: maybe you forgot to restart php-fpm after editing/removing config files? `sudo /etc/init.d/php7.1-fpm restart`

Comment: Hi, no I do valet restart each time. I'm using VSC but that should not be relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Heh!

Turns out that doing valet restart and seeing:

[image]

Does not actually restart a PHP!!!

on the other hand:

[image]

Works as expected and does show the correct files being parsed now.

Thank you very much for suggestion. I was just 100% I was actually restarting my php-fpm with the above command.

Comment: Typical "did you try to turning it off and on?". Delete the question and the answer its not SO related and belongs to serverfault anyway. Also do not post pictures, you can easily copy from the iTerm - obviously in the comments its going to suck but answer/question body is good to go: `➜  Laravel art tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.6 (PHP 7.1.14 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> now()
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1528791730 {#2911
     date: 2018-06-12 08:22:10.406959 UTC (+00:00),
   }`

Comment: Well thanks a lot for you kind replay. As you can see it is Laravel Valet related since the command that you expect to restart php, does not actually restart it. Yes - I did try turing it off and on again. No - it did not work. Yes - I deared to ask a stupid question and was only waiting for first super nice member to tell me I'm an Idiot. Your are awesome. I'm an idiot. Got it.

Comment: Look at the code of valet https://github.com/laravel/valet/blob/08932644cf3dbd167e509ee3946a266e3a71e235/cli/Valet/Brew.php#L142-L154 it is doing exact same thing as you*. Try this `ps -ax | grep php-fpm` note the PIDs and use `valet restart` did PIDs change? Conclusion: valet does its job fine, you did your testing wrongly. *It executes `stop` and `start` commands not `restart`.

Comment: Ok I agree, but then explain to me please, why is my solution working and yours does not work? Maybe there is a difference between brew services stop/start and brew services restart?

Comment: Since there is an issue in valet repository you will most likely get an answer there - https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/597

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. We already know that there is the problem and we know how to fix it. I also reported the issue. Yet you have to prove that you are smarter and you can post links. If you are so smart then why don't you simply fix it and do a pull request? I'm an idiot but I'm sure you can fix that issue in no time.

Comment: Your assumption that something is wrong with valet is not reproducible I tried both approaches and both worked for me, so there is no problem in the valet (on my machine). I am convinced you are just testing it with a wrong approach. Also why do you keep telling us how stupid you are, there is no reason for this kind of comments.

Comment: Well if you look at your first comment then you would know why: Typical "did you try to turning it off and on?". Delete the question and the answer its not SO related and belongs to serverfault anyway... Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Yet again bashing for no reason... did you read other parts of the comment?